# Mysql select query which can select all rows of a field and some rows of another fields

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to make a search system.When a user want to search he/she should select the options from select boxes in a form.The first option for all select boxes should be 'All'.I need a mysql query which can select all rows of one or more fields and some spesific rows of another fields in a table.Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: share your tables structure and sample desired data..

Comment: you can use left outer join for implementing it

Comment: @User3114651 could you please write an example query for my question?

Comment: @ZafarMalik the search is between different fields of one table.My problem is how to select all records of one or more fields

Comment: SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;

NOTE- There should be common columns in both ie column_name of one table should be equal to another table Column_Name (not the names i mean with the values).

check: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.... there should be plenty of resources online for that

SQL requests follow SELECT, FROM , WHERE in syntax. The WHERE part is optional, just a way to target specific values. SELECT says what information is returned, FROM says from which collection of data, also known as the table, it is coming from.The column_name or table_name can be replaced with a wildcard like "*", which gets everything.

ie SELECT column_name
   FROM   table_name
   WHERE  specific_condition

If this confuses you have a look at w3schools.com they have plenty of tutorials for SQL.